# Virtual device (AVD , Android 4.4) failed to run every-time ? why?

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, homescreen

I am a new learner of android development .When I was creating an AVD then it said that "on windows emulating RAM greater than 768M may fail depending upon system load.Try progressively smaller values of RAM if the emulator fails to launch" . respective screen shots are as fallows :

warning

[image]

stuck:

[image]

I tried to decrease the RAM size after that and tried 400 instead of 1024 but it couldn't open the AVD home page .I waited more than one hour but all in vain .I am using Android 4.4 API level 19 .I don't know why this happening and stuck at this situation.I want to know that where is the problem ,why it's not running .My PC configuration is : 
OS: Windows 7 RAM: 2 GB Processor : Core2Duo

Comment: May I know why someone ranked it as -1 ? What kind of arrogance is this ? Can't a new learner be allowed to ask something at stackoverflow ??

Answer (score 0):

AVD is quite slow at times. Tips to speed it up significantly:

- Download the Intel x86 Atom System Image from your Android SDK Manager for API 19
- Then download and install
  https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager
- If you have a graphics card I would try to enable Host GPU option
- Example settings for your AVD:

  ```
  -      CPU/ABI: Intel Atom (x86)
  -      Emulation Options: Use Host GPU
  ```

Comment: thanks for you help ,but again its quiet absurd the way people here ready to down vote a post and its pretty evident that someone also down voted your answer when you just trying to help somebody .its hell rude :/ alas if we could have more people like you who prefer to help rather condemn !